# AS3 face features recognition library

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking for a face features recognition library in AS3, I mean one which detects through the webcam the expression of the user ( sad, happy, serious, and so on ).

I've been told there is a library from a french dude for this kind of stuff which sends JSON with info about user face params but had no luck finding it.

Does anyone knows anything about this library ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [Face Recognition Library - Google code](http://code.google.com/p/face-recognition-library-as3/)??

I found [this blog post](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php) about face detection quite some time ago, check if thats what you want.

Comment: Not exactly, I've been playing with that face recognition example before asking here and I need to process the webcam outcome and get some kind of measurable output to detect the user expression. I've found some C++ libs but nothing written on as3.

Comment: "face.com" api is what I was looking for